# Couldn't get sed to match a group

Tags: sed, macos

I'm trying to do the below:

```
echo "/Users/anon/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Spotify.app" |
 sed -E 's:([^\/]*$).*:\1:'
```

which I assumed would capture `Spotify.app` and replace the entire string with it, but this doesn't work. Instead, I get the entire string back.

So, I thought maybe my regex is wrong, so I did the below to test it out:

```
echo "/Users/anon/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Spotify.app" |
 sed 's:[^\/]*$:PWA.app:'
```

But I get the expected output: `/Users/anon/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/PWA.app`.

So, I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. Why is the same regex not getting matched when grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it more complex than it needs to be.

```
sed -e 's:.*/::'
```

Let the greediness of regexes do the work for you. The `.*` will quickly overshoot all the way to the end of the string, but then it needsto match a hard slash, so the regex engine begins to backtrack, looking for a / and stops at the first / it encounters on its way back. => last slash of the string. We just remove until this point and we are implicitly left with what is after the last slash and end of string.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It *is* getting matched, then you turn around and backsubstitute the matched value right back where you found it. Note that `.*` cannot match anything *after* `$`.

Presumably you want something like <strike>`s:.*([^/]*$):\1:`</strike> except that won't work because sed will greedily consume everything into the `.*` . You could do it in perl using the non-greedy modifier:

```
$ echo "/Users/anon/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Spotify.app" | 
    perl -pe 's:.*?([^/]*$):\1:'
Spotify.app
```

In sed, you could fake non-greediness by matching 0 or more `/` terminated path components:

```
$ echo "/Users/anon/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Spotify.app" | 
    sed -E 's:([^/]*/)*(.*)$:\2:'
Spotify.app
```

However if you're doing this in any POSIX supporting shell, you may find it simpler to use shell parameter expansion to remove the longest path match:

```
$ var="/Users/anon/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Spotify.app"
$ echo "${var##*/}"
Spotify.app
```

Comment: You could just do `sed -E 's:.*/([^/]*)$:\1:'`, also.

Comment: ... or `basename "$pathname"`.

Comment: OP, Got it. Thanks for the explanation. @terdon, that does it for me as well stopping .* consuming everything. Thank you!